# What tools do I need to use to report a bug in a developers PPA?

Tags: bug-reporting

When you want to report an error the best way to report a package in Ubuntu is                                   `sudo ubuntu-bug package`.

But what if the package is in a developers PPA and I want to report an error with enough information, what tools can I use to generate that necessary information?

Comment: I mean, pidgin is not an official package of ubuntu.
  as I can make a correct report and upload it to the account of the pidgin developers launchpad

Comment: Are you asking specifically how to report *non-crash* bugs in PPA-provided software? For a crash in official Ubuntu software, `ubuntu-bug packagename` or `sudo ubuntu-bug packagename` is only *very rarely* the best way (or even an acceptably good way) to file a report. Crash bugs should be submitted with backtraces. Apport can be configured to "jump" on crashes that occur in official packages and in a tiny minority of unofficial packages; otherwise the best course is to manually run `gdb` to get the trace. Please let us know if you're trying to report *crash* bugs--if so, I can add an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Ubuntu project & community does not take responsibility for PPA and their packages. The only packages that the Ubuntu community maintains are the ones found in the **main**, **restricted**, **universe** and **multiverse** repository.

Most of the times, there is no way to use Ubuntu standard tools (like **Apport**) to report bugs against non-Ubuntu packages. You have just two options when you find a bug in a package provided by a PPA:

1. If you think the bug is also in the Ubuntu "official" package, then remove the PPA package and test the Ubuntu package. If the bug can be reproduced, use **ubuntu-bug** to report it.
2. If the bug is only in the PPA package, you should get in touch with the maintainer(s) of the PPA. They will give you instructions about how to report the bug.